# Find envelope of $x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta + z = a \theta$, where $\theta$ is a parameter.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have tried to find envelope for
$$x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta + z = a \theta$$
First I find derivative w.r.t. $\theta$
$$F(\theta)=x \sin \theta - y \cos \theta + z - a \theta = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial F(\theta)}{\partial \theta}=y \sin \theta + x \cos \theta - a = 0$$
Then by solving these two above equation in order to eliminate parameter $\theta$, I find values of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$
$$\sin \theta = \frac{ax\theta + ay - xz}{x^2 + y^2}$$
and
$$\cos \theta = \frac{ax - ay\theta + yz}{x^2 + y^2}$$
Finally to find value of $\theta$ I squares and add above two equations then I get a quadratic equation in $\theta$ as
$$a^2\theta^2 - 2az\theta + a^2 + z^2 - x^2 - y^2=0$$
Then solving this for $\theta$ by applying quadratic formula, I get condition for real values of $\theta$ i.e.

$\theta$ is real only if
$$x^2+y^2 \ge a^2$$

Now here is my question. **Either $x^2+y^2 \ge a^2$ is required envelope or something more to do?**
Because $x^2+y^2 \ge a^2$ is an equality in which we have eliminated parameter $\theta$.

Comment: No, the envelope is a curve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust then what I have to do more?

Comment: Eliminate $\theta$ from the system of equations, solve the quadratic equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have find values of sin and cos. And also two different values of $\theta$. Then I have two envelope equations for two different values of $\theta$. will it be fine to have two different envelopes for one family of planes?

Comment: Why not, if the equations say so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You get rid of the annoying trigonometric functions by

$$(z-a\theta)^2+a^2=x^2+y^2.$$

From this you draw $\theta$, which you plug in one of the initial equations. Not a really nice expression.

---

Alternatively, in cylindrical coordinates $(\phi,\rho)$ we rewrite

$$\begin{cases}\rho\sin(\phi-\theta)=z-a\theta,\\\rho\cos(\phi-\theta)=a.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\phi=\theta+\arccos\frac a\rho=\frac{z\pm\sqrt{\rho^2-a^2}}a+\arccos\frac a\rho.$$

Comment: Thanks for giving me a more clean result in alternative form. I hope it is the required envelope.